# Conda cannot find package despite package being listed on anaconda.org

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, mini-forge

I am trying to install `zipline-reloaded` using `conda` but am encountering a `PackagesNotFoundError`—this despite running the install command for `zipline-reloaded` provided on the [package's page](https://anaconda.org/ml4t/zipline-reloaded) on anaconda.org. What might be going wrong here, and how can I resolve it?

My steps this far:

1. `conda create -n zipline python=3.8`
2. `conda activate zipline`
3. `conda install -c ml4t zipline-reloaded` (this is directly from the package's page on anaconda.org, linked above, but raises `PackagesNotFoundError`)

Note that trying to install, e.g., `scipy`, yields no similar error. Also, using `mamba` instead of `conda` leads to the same `PackagesNotFoundError` error.

The output of `conda info` is below:

```
active environment : zipline
active env location : /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/zipline
shell level : 1
user config file : /Users/name/.condarc
populated config files : /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/.condarc
                         /Users/name/.condarc
conda version : 22.9.0
conda-build version : not installed
python version : 3.9.15.final.0
virtual packages : __osx=12.4=0
                   __unix=0=0
                   __archspec=1=arm64
base environment : /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base  (writable)
conda av data dir : /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/etc/conda
conda av metadata url : None
channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/ml4t/osx-arm64
               https://conda.anaconda.org/ml4t/noarch
               https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
               https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
               https://conda.anaconda.org/ranaroussi/osx-arm64
               https://conda.anaconda.org/ranaroussi/noarch
package cache : /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs
                /Users/name/.conda/pkgs
envs directories : /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs
                   /Users/name/.conda/envs
platform : osx-arm64
user-agent : conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.15 Darwin/21.5.0 OSX/12.4
UID:GID : 501:20
netrc file : None
offline mode : False
```

I've tried running:

```bash
conda clean -all
conda clean --index-cache
conda update conda
```

I've also made sure to set offline mode to false (`conda config --set offline false`), which it is, per the output above.

Finally, running `conda search -c ml4t zipline-reloaded -vvv` outputs:

```bash
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(236): verbosity set to 3
Loading channels: ...working... TRACE conda.gateways.disk.test:file_path_is_writable(24): checking path is writable /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/urls.txt
DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(268): package cache directory '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs' writable: True
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(273): Local cache timed out for https://conda.anaconda.org/ml4t/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/b4814506.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(273): Local cache timed out for https://conda.anaconda.org/ml4t/noarch/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/091140c5.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(273): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/4ea078d6.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(273): Local cache timed out for https://conda.anaconda.org/ranaroussi/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/639ecbbd.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(267): Using cached repodata for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/09cdf8bf.json. Timeout in 42 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(273): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/8bd55712.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(273): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/3e39a7aa.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(357): found pickle file /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/09cdf8bf.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(273): Local cache timed out for https://conda.anaconda.org/ranaroussi/noarch/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/f2f1db2e.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(267): Using cached repodata for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/a850f475.json. Timeout in 37 sec
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(273): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/9e99ffaf.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(357): found pickle file /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/a850f475.q
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1003): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /ml4t/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(530): 
>>GET /ml4t/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.15 Darwin/21.5.0 OSX/12.4
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> If-Modified-Since: Sun, 27 Nov 2022 23:15:46 GMT

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< CF-Ray: 7729c305af6cc3f0-EWR
< Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:16 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=5_iHfkEj0MHUfLTzo1_JU44eFH7k.fkG4MefCLHFwCs-1669876096-0-Afv4K+DTTGsbF/EJ55ZMcprcOQU03A9xjLx1fVCxk220/+qEj2KgM0D9KShLZZMNwWIGCF/SrfFT/0yOU8PYUb3c1sef5rFCHNw00EumeSIB; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Dec-22 06:58:16 GMT; domain=.anaconda.org; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.374252


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(292): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://conda.anaconda.org/ml4t/osx-arm64/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.update:touch(132): touching path /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/b4814506.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /ranaroussi/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(530): 
>>GET /ranaroussi/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.15 Darwin/21.5.0 OSX/12.4
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> If-Modified-Since: Sat, 10 Jul 2021 20:29:09 GMT

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< CF-Ray: 7729c305b931c436-EWR
< Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:16 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=L8JbFm6EySvGhs3b0c54CFobV5MnnDkLYszHBXNbkOE-1669876096-0-AXqlxjWUQxlASGQq2FDCPHAie99ZATvZmSa+RepV64uBbnR2GAeRM3oe+VMrkj23RXFUNlC8xP/j689pu+kPxuVwr5M1u96nKabCLWSujD5q; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Dec-22 06:58:16 GMT; domain=.anaconda.org; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.449782


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(292): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://conda.anaconda.org/ranaroussi/osx-arm64/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.update:touch(132): touching path /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/639ecbbd.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(357): found pickle file /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/b4814506.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(357): found pickle file /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/639ecbbd.q
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /ml4t/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(530): 
>>GET /ml4t/noarch/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.15 Darwin/21.5.0 OSX/12.4
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> If-Modified-Since: Sun, 27 Nov 2022 23:15:46 GMT

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< CF-Ray: 7729c306acba17a5-EWR
< Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:17 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=OUlfjhiwUIls5GRrkrvx_gSvGNQ8jSFq4C4FQHuUEkI-1669876097-0-AeZAUF8zYwue32HP8rVUfV7ws8cYe8P/MZIXlS5tWbRONDfIemqH4Ze4eE1R6UuAdqaqqw/Rh2jJscMkBWdApRdTtKFIYda2yA5HJ44Urw+N; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Dec-22 06:58:17 GMT; domain=.anaconda.org; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.531916


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(292): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://conda.anaconda.org/ml4t/noarch/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(530): 
>>GET /pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.15 Darwin/21.5.0 OSX/12.4
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> If-Modified-Since: Fri, 19 Aug 2022 21:27:22 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"bd18071599942dd824e1ec40e9d10873"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 70484
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 7729c306daf41899-EWR
< Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:17 GMT
< ETag: "bd18071599942dd824e1ec40e9d10873"
< Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:47 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 03 May 2022 07:57:20 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=JAZuB9kuZKjDvy1WXV.IHe1gCAnfEEZIs2uQ0YOh.nY-1669876097-0-AcbFb9BTBsrUintQD6w4DP0qheARYSHDdmj1IfpgfRRjTdJlAeFbjfAQhX/8gthx2K7VCEDYMRtjVnJGkgyCwUw=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Dec-22 06:58:17 GMT; domain=.anaconda.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: fY9HZBoI/58riYlxXBQEYfV8bKmFamLhAbhZ0J9i5X/O76LU6Xv7DmrLw/lA4gHYZlTeq3dMEDM=
< x-amz-request-id: YY7S26ZWVFSN8T0M
< x-amz-version-id: PxKW1ua_FXQgEcZyls93YYZW2aaplpSK
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.524347


DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(292): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.update:touch(132): touching path /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/091140c5.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(530): 
>>GET /pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.15 Darwin/21.5.0 OSX/12.4
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> If-Modified-Since: Wed, 30 Nov 2022 19:20:01 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"1d4ef7661a7ed1933c0a6c41ba4cc425"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 39940
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 7729c306dadbc431-EWR
< Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:17 GMT
< ETag: "1d4ef7661a7ed1933c0a6c41ba4cc425"
< Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:47 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 30 Nov 2022 19:20:01 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=7x27GyPAJ_UqkTJ5ao1cZqqBeayN2Vq_70IaoJpxzR8-1669876097-0-ATY8FjtZs8mdSSsf4qFxF152kwLQLqkVqwVancCZTg2qapMhP1+FEa/52Z+AOF4oswA3GiYn7Uix0Aw73CW0GRs=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Dec-22 06:58:17 GMT; domain=.anaconda.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: Uish9rt+JimvRr8GdFZh7QAY41ytOYotp0TpctIyZ20CIAjj/6MuY/CWhjDJpjKlCv1rRqREnwY=
< x-amz-request-id: JVFF0K2E15ZN38V9
< x-amz-version-id: NpiUwg7Fl941vKA3jucFV5n6mUv51EJP
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.524693


TRACE conda.gateways.disk.update:touch(132): touching path /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/8bd55712.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(530): 
>>GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.15 Darwin/21.5.0 OSX/12.4
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> If-Modified-Since: Tue, 29 Nov 2022 16:03:07 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"6e04ba60f4112b8b66a702155b149789"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 138272
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 7729c306da4b8c45-EWR
< Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:17 GMT
< ETag: "6e04ba60f4112b8b66a702155b149789"
< Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:47 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Nov 2022 16:03:07 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=8QKdusunJ3shgZum2CdhgDnvVSZar0.5gchEPAhnDBY-1669876097-0-AegybkAav3z1xItNVSkXgTOadb6BWGFIkf1h503nEQXjDZzXBwfpUPK6FUZ2NL6Lm1Vp5CzzYIbuW8VJDG2RDGo=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Dec-22 06:58:17 GMT; domain=.anaconda.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: XOcwXl6k5xoUe4CZu165pl5DxNRL491AX2Bo9oR0kKVB7C17o3jsWbDG9NiZYZJdTx5oBpaxcqA=
< x-amz-request-id: GVVB079XW40XCD4Q
< x-amz-version-id: Q4_RUh4DCA9G9p4t7FVjTf1kw3tFux..
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.530062


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(530): 
>>GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.15 Darwin/21.5.0 OSX/12.4
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> If-Modified-Since: Fri, 28 Oct 2022 15:33:23 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"93476d5e7aa8d3f8bc0c04afafc94d26"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 485667
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 7729c306dc0918d0-EWR
< Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:17 GMT
< ETag: "93476d5e7aa8d3f8bc0c04afafc94d26"
< Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:47 GMT
< Last-Modified: Fri, 28 Oct 2022 15:33:23 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=RY6dkW_AH.MOyDqWGMA8yJp41UzE7C0EjdUA6z.qv2E-1669876097-0-AX/HkmV1qRZQ5J/UH1Z0z4SbLecq+BzVhaoJGmrI2vgoIR/bJv2tfkoNqHeerl3ZI2S6oqtRb8P0Gav35+nOgOY=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Dec-22 06:58:17 GMT; domain=.anaconda.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: D6P8KXSXC8gI7KOzlv0g5TO90T3ZSLUoRW6bdyxr5QPE9G0npKKYCVCJxA2sG2SUDPMQvTjcbxg=
< x-amz-request-id: PRT6QH04241S05D7
< x-amz-version-id: gruUyeXEAuhL5g34laDjUOasClLQRFQz
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.531401


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(292): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(292): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(357): found pickle file /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/091140c5.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(292): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.update:touch(132): touching path /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/9e99ffaf.json
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.update:touch(132): touching path /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/4ea078d6.json
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.update:touch(132): touching path /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/3e39a7aa.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(357): found pickle file /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/8bd55712.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(357): found pickle file /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/4ea078d6.q
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(456): https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /ranaroussi/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(530): 
>>GET /ranaroussi/noarch/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.15 Darwin/21.5.0 OSX/12.4
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> If-Modified-Since: Sat, 10 Jul 2021 20:29:09 GMT

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< CF-Ray: 7729c306eae4c44f-EWR
< Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2022 06:28:17 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=z8IMtaIACkUQIrN4AAyFQZdV13R.rBlauiHJyaXMD84-1669876097-0-AeYOO899tSB0BSkyr1RX+7rzFGl8/m2XUWEw0WLe4gaVuzuEzaTXes5vpeUhvoSew0ZVOGdKRcf404U90fpX+srJDKTNNlvNf+wjflTXFgmU; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Dec-22 06:58:17 GMT; domain=.anaconda.org; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.645770


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(292): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://conda.anaconda.org/ranaroussi/noarch/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.update:touch(132): touching path /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/f2f1db2e.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(357): found pickle file /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/9e99ffaf.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(375): Pickle load validation failed for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/8bd55712.json.
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(357): found pickle file /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/3e39a7aa.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_local_repdata(330): Loading raw json for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/8bd55712.json
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(357): found pickle file /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/f2f1db2e.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_pickle_me(316): Saving pickled state for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/cache/8bd55712.q
done
No match found for: zipline-reloaded. Search: *zipline-reloaded*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1129, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 86, in main_subshell
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 93, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_search.py", line 89, in execute
    raise PackagesNotFoundError((str(spec),), channels_urls)
conda.exceptions.PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
```

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64651410/conda-cannot-find-packages-to-install), but none of the solutions outlined there solve the issue.

Comment: Try installing from conda-forge channel: `conda install -c ml4t -c conda-forge -c ranaroussi zipline-reloaded`

Comment: @Python16367225, this results in the same error absent any changes—however, works with the fix I share in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to install onto a mac with an arm processor (see `platform : osx-arm64` in the output of `conda info`). But https://anaconda.org/ml4t/zipline-reloaded shows the channel you are attempting to install from does not have an `osx-arm64` build.

Answer (score 1):

Will Holtz was right in pointing out that the problem stems from my being on an M1 Mac and there not yet being a build of `zipline-reloaded` for M1 Macs. A full answer, however, would also give a resolution. The solution below, copied from [here](https://github.com/Haydnspass/miniforge#rosetta-on-mac-with-apple-silicon-hardware), did the trick for me:

```
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n [environment]  # create a new environment
conda activate [environment]
conda env config vars set CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64  # subsequent commands use intel packages
```